# R Shiny collect multiple reactive input value and pass to plot

Tags: r, shiny

I have a dataframe:

```
df1<-data.frame(ID1=c("A","A","B"),
                ID2=c("A","B","C"),
                Value=1:3)
```

I would like to generate reactive barplot which can show uniqe item of the data whatever the group I choose.
the ui:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      # fileInput("file1","File"),
      selectInput("select1","Select a group",choices = names(df1)),
      actionButton("submit1","Submit"),
      uiOutput("ui1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('show_inputs'),
      textOutput("show_inputs_text"),
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)
```

the server:

```
server <- function(input, output){
  df2<-reactive({df1})
  temptV<-reactive({
    as.matrix(
      unique(
        df2() %>%
          select(input$select1)
      )
    )
  })
  ve<-isolate(list())
  co<-isolate(list())
  observeEvent(input$submit1,{
    for(i in 1:length(temptV())){
      ve[[i]]<-colourpicker::colourInput(
        inputId = paste0("colorID",i),
        label= paste0(temptV()[i])
      )
      co[[i]]<-paste0("colorID",i)
    }
    output$ui1<-renderUI(
      ve
    )
    
    ##check the output of reactiveValuesToList
    t1<-reactive({
      x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
      data.frame(
        names = names(x),
        values = unlist(x, use.names = FALSE)
      )
    })
    output$show_inputs <- renderTable({
      t1()
    })
    output$show_inputs_text <- renderText({
      unlist(co)
    })
    #plot
    p<-reactive(
      ggplot(df1,aes(x=df1[,input$select1],y=df1[,"Value"],fill=df1[,input$select1]))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
        scale_fill_manual(values = t1()[t1()$names %in% unlist(co),"values"])
      )
    output$plot1<-renderPlot(
      p()
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

I used a loop to generate `i` number of the colorinput based on the unique items of the group in `df1`, and I collect the colorinput IDs in `co`. Then I used the `reactiveValuesToList` to fetch all input IDs and subset those in `co` and pass the corresponding values to the bar plot `scale_fill_manual`.

It works like:
When there are two unique item, two colorinput and two bars:
[image]
When there are three unique item, three colorinput and three bars:
[image]

However, when I added `fileInput` in the ui, the results in `reactiveValuesToList` became a chaos and I was not able to collect the exact IDs for the `scale_fill_manual`,like:
[image]

Any suggestion to deal with this problem? Or is there any easy way to achieve my purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue is that until you load a file, `file1` is `NULL`. When you create `t1` from `input` it will include `file1 = NULL`. Therefore, you have a valid name for the `names` column of the `data.frame` but no corresponding value to put in `values` which is what's giving the error you see about different numbers of rows.

Since you don't want to see the parts of `input` related to the file upload in `t1`(whether or not one is added), you can just remove that in either case with `x[!grepl("file", names(x))]`.

I also converted all the variables in `df1` to `factor` so they will work with a discrete color palette.

```r
library(shiny)

df1<-data.frame(ID1=c("A","A","B"),
                ID2=c("A","B","C"),
                Value=factor(1:3))

ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("file1","File"),
      selectInput("select1","Select a group",choices = names(df1)),
      actionButton("submit1","Submit"),
      uiOutput("ui1")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput('show_inputs'),
      textOutput("show_inputs_text"),
      plotOutput("plot1")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df2<-reactive({df1})
  temptV<-reactive({
    as.matrix(
      unique(
        df2() %>%
          select(input$select1)
      )
    )
  })
  ve<-isolate(list())
  co<-isolate(list())
  observeEvent(input$submit1,{
    for(i in 1:length(temptV())){
      ve[[i]]<-colourpicker::colourInput(
        inputId = paste0("colorID",i),
        label= paste0(temptV()[i])
      )
      co[[i]]<-paste0("colorID",i)
    }
    output$ui1<-renderUI(
      ve
    )
    
    ##check the output of reactiveValuesToList
    t1<-reactive({
      x <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
      data.frame(
        names = names(x[!grepl("file", names(x))]),
        values = unlist(x[!grepl("file", names(x))], use.names = FALSE)
      )
    })
    output$show_inputs <- renderTable({
      t1()
    })
    output$show_inputs_text <- renderText({
      unlist(co)
    })
    #plot
    p<-reactive(
      ggplot(df1,aes(x=df1[,input$select1],y=df1[,"Value"],fill=df1[,input$select1]))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
        scale_fill_manual(values = t1()[t1()$names %in% unlist(co),"values"])
    )
    output$plot1<-renderPlot(
      p()
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui,server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, I tried and it worked when no file was uploaded, but failed when file was uploaded, any idea to solve it? Thanks again

Comment: See update. FYI - adding breakpoints or `browser()` statements to inspect the intermediate data object such as `x` or `t1` is very helpful. It's how I diagnosed this, so I encourage you to try it out.

Comment: For more info on this check out [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/debugging.html) article.